# Mathematical Function Returning NaN Error (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nan

I am trying to fix a NaN error.

When running the code on the console it gives me the correct answer. However, when I try to print it on a HTML H1 tag the code returns a NaN error.

I tried to use native functions (ie.: parseFloat(), .toString();), but it didn't work as planned.

Could you shed a light, please?

```js
const tempConvert = parseFloat (document.querySelector('input'));

function convertTemp(tempConvert) {
    switch (slt.value) {
        case 'farenheit':
            document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = `${convertCToF(tempConvert)} Fº`;
            break;
        case 'kelvin':
            document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = `${convertCToK(tempConvert)} Kº`;
            break;
        default:
            alert('Selec an option.');
            break;
    }
}


function convertCToF(tempC) {
    return tempC * 1.8 + 32;
}

function convertCToK(tempC) {
    return tempC + 273.15;
}
```

Comment: hint: `document.querySelector('input')` returns an HTMLInput element - you may as well be doing `parseFloat(document.body)` - it makes as much sense

Comment: What is `slt.value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get `input.value`, not `input`. `document.querySelector('input')` is going to give you the HTML Element of `input`. If you `console.log` that, you will see it has a bunch of properties and among them is `value`, which contains the text inside the `input` tag.

Also, it's generally a better idea to use `innerText` than to use `innerHTML` whenever possible due to security reasons.

```js
const slt = {
  value: 'farenheit'
}

function convertTemp(tempConvert) {
  console.log("Hello");
  switch (slt.value) {
    case 'farenheit':
      document.querySelector('h1').innerText = `${convertCToF(tempConvert)} Fº`;
      break;
    case 'kelvin':
      document.querySelector('h1').innerText = `${convertCToK(tempConvert)} Kº`;
      break;
    default:
      alert('Selec an option.');
      break;
  }
}

document.querySelector("#myBtn").addEventListener('click', () => convertTemp(document.querySelector('input').value));

function convertCToF(tempC) {
  return tempC * 1.8 + 32;
}

function convertCToK(tempC) {
  return tempC + 273.15;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' />
<button id="myBtn">Convert</button>

<h1>Result Here</h1>
```